# Neural Network Trains Fine and Test Predictions are Horrible Bordering on Ridiculous

Tags: machine-learning, modeling, prediction

I am having a lot of trouble with a neural network model using R neuralnet() function.  When I train a network on all of the data as expected the predictions are very accurate.  However, when I split the data into training and test sets, the test predictions are terrible.  I cannot figure what all I am doing wrong.  I would appreciate any advice or help troubleshooting as I don't think I'll be able to figure this out on my own.  Thanks in advance.

I have included the R code and some plots and an example of the data below the full data is 3600 observations.

Best Regards-Pat

UPDATE 05/12/18: BASED ON FEEDBACK THAT THIS LOOKS LIKE OVERFITTING, I TRIED STOPPING THE TRAINING EARLIER AND FOUND THAT THE MSE OF THE TEST PREDICTION NEVER GETS VERY LOW AND IS LOWEST APPROACHING 0 TRAINING EPOCHS AND RISES FROM THERE (PLOT INCLUDED AND CODE APPENDED)

```
###########
#ANN Models
###########

#Load libraries
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(neuralnet)

#Retain only numerically coded data from data1 in (data2) for ANN fitting
data2 = data1[,c(3:7)]

#Calculate Min and Max for Scaling
max_data = apply(data2,2,max)
min_data = apply(data2,2,min)
#Scale data 0-1
data2_scaled = scale(data2,center=min_data,scale=max_data-min_data)
#Check data structure
data2_scaled

#Fit neural net model
model_nn1 = neuralnet(formula=time~instructions+nodes+machine_num+app_num,data=data2_scaled,hidden=c(8,8),stepmax=1000000,threshold=0.01)
#Calculate Min and Max Response for rescaling
max_time = max(data2$time)
min_time = min(data2$time)
#Rescale neural net response predictions
pred_nn1 = model_nn1$net.result[[1]][,1]*(max_time-min_time)+min_time
#Compare model predictions to actual values
a03 = cbind.data.frame(data1$time,pred_nn1,data1$machine,data1$app)
colnames(a03) = c("actual","prediction","machine","app")
attach(a03)
p01 = ggplot(a03,aes(x=actual,y=prediction))+
geom_point(aes(color=machine),size=1)+
scale_y_continuous("Predicted Execution Time [s]",breaks=seq(0,1000,100),limits=c(0,1000))+
scale_x_continuous("Actual Execution Time [s]",breaks=seq(0,1000,100),limits=c(0,1000))+
ggtitle("Neural Net Fit (ALL DATA):\nActual vs. Predicted Execution Time")+
geom_abline(intercept=0,slope=1)+
theme_light()
p02 = ggplot(a03,aes(x=actual,y=prediction))+
geom_point(aes(color=app),size=1)+
scale_y_continuous("Predicted Execution Time [s]",breaks=seq(0,1000,100),limits=c(0,1000))+
scale_x_continuous("Actual Execution Time [s]",breaks=seq(0,1000,100),limits=c(0,1000))+
ggtitle("Neural Net Fit (ALL DATA):\nActual vs. Predicted Execution Time")+
geom_abline(intercept=0,slope=1)+
theme_light()
grid.arrange(p01,p02,nrow=1)
#Visualize ANN
plot(model_nn1)
#Epochs taken to train "steps"
model_nn1$result.matrix[3,]

#########################
#Testing and Training ANN
#########################>

#Split the data into a test and training set
index = sample(1:nrow(data2_scaled),round(0.80*nrow(data2_scaled)))
train_data = as.data.frame(data2_scaled[index,])
test_data = as.data.frame(data2_scaled[-index,])
model_nn2 = neuralnet(formula=time~instructions+nodes+machine_num+app_num,data=train_data,hidden=c(3,2),stepmax=1000000,threshold=0.01)
pred_nn2_scaled = compute(model_nn2,test_data[,c(1,2,4,5)])
pred_nn2 = pred_nn2_scaled$net.result*(max_time-min_time)+min_time
test_data_time = test_data$time*(max_time-min_time)+min_time
a04 = cbind.data.frame(test_data_time,pred_nn2,data1[-index,2],data1[-index,1])
colnames(a04) = c("actual","prediction","machine","app")
attach(a04)
p01 = ggplot(a04,aes(x=actual,y=prediction))+
geom_point(aes(color=machine),size=1)+
scale_y_continuous("Predicted Execution Time [s]",breaks=seq(0,1000,100),limits=c(0,1000))+
scale_x_continuous("Actual Execution Time [s]",breaks=seq(0,1000,100),limits=c(0,1000))+
ggtitle("Neural Net Fit (TEST DATA):\nActual vs. Predicted Execution Time")+
geom_abline(intercept=0,slope=1)+
theme_light()
p02 = ggplot(a04,aes(x=actual,y=prediction))+
geom_point(aes(color=app),size=1)+
scale_y_continuous("Predicted Execution Time [s]",breaks=seq(0,1000,100),limits=c(0,1000))+
scale_x_continuous("Actual Execution Time [s]",breaks=seq(0,1000,100),limits=c(0,1000))+
ggtitle("Neural Net Fit (TEST DATA):\nActual vs. Predicted Execution Time")+
geom_abline(intercept=0,slope=1)+
theme_light()
grid.arrange(p01,p02,nrow=1)

#EARLY STOPPING TEST

i = 1000
summary_data = data.frame(matrix(rep(0,4*i),ncol=4))
colnames(summary_data) = c("treshold","epochs","train_mse","test_mse")
for (j in 1:i){
a = runif(1,min=0.01,max=10)
#Train the model
model_nn2 = neuralnet(formula=time~instructions+nodes+machine_num+app_num,data=train_data,hidden=3,stepmax=1000000,threshold=a)
#Calculate Min and Max Response for rescaling
max_time = max(data2$time)
min_time = min(data2$time)
#Predict test data from trained nn
pred_nn2_scaled = compute(model_nn2,test_data[,c(1,2,4,5)])
#Rescale test prediction
pred_test_data_time = pred_nn2_scaled$net.result*(max_time-min_time)+min_time
#Rescale test actual
test_data_time = test_data$time*(max_time-min_time)+min_time
#Rescale train prediction
pred_train_data_time = model_nn2$net.result[[1]][,1]*(max_time-min_time)+min_time
#Rescale train actual
train_data_time = train_data$time*(max_time-min_time)+min_time
#Calculate mse
test_mse = mean((pred_test_data_time-test_data_time)^2)
train_mse = mean((pred_train_data_time-train_data_time)^2)
#Summarize
summary_data[j,1] = a
summary_data[j,2] = model_nn2$result.matrix[3,]
summary_data[j,3] = round(train_mse,3)
summary_data[j,4] = round(test_mse,3)
print(summary_data[j,])
}

plot(summary_data$epochs,summary_data$test_mse,pch=19,xlim=c(0,2000),ylim=c(0,300000),cex=0.5,xlab="Training Steps",ylab="MSE",main="Early Stopping Test: Comparing MSE : TEST=BLACK TRAIN=RED")
points(summary_data$epochs,summary_data$train_mse,pch=19,col=2,cex=0.5)
```

[image: Training Predictions]

[image: Test Predictions]

[image: data2 example]

[image: EARLY STOPPING TEST]

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that it is overfitting. The network is learning to reproduce the data like a dictionary instead of learning the underlying function in the data. There are various things which can cause this and ways to address them.
Things which cause overfitting are:

- The network could be training for too long.
- The network could having far more weights than training examples.

Ways to reduce overfitting are:

- Create a validation dataset and stop training the network as soon as the
  validation set's loss starts increasing. This is a necessity.
- Reducing the network size. (Less weights)
- Using a regularization technique like weight decay or dropout.

Also, it may be possible that the problem is too difficult for a neural network to solve based on the data it is given. Reproducing training data does not prove that the network can solve the problem, it only proves that the network can remember things like a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the direction Nathan, your response makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Hi Nathan, I’m going to try adjusting some of the arguments to the neuralnet() function, based on your 3 bullets to reduce overfitting.  Do you have any good references on your first bullet point, for monitoring loss during validation set training?

Comment: @PatrickJ, I googled a bit but couldn't find a nice article on it. Training a neural network is an iterative process, as you train the network, the loss (or error) of the network will decrease. I havn't worked with R myself so R might be doing some of this behind the scenes. Consider this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QU0m.png. 'Training Error' decreases overtime as the network is trained. The 'test error' initially starts decreasing but then once overfitting starts to occur then it starts to increase. That point is marked 'Early stopping' because that is where you will stop training. 1/2

Comment: You will split your dataset into 3 groups: test set, validation set, train set. You use the validation set to test for overfitting.
The algorthm to train will look like this:
`while True:

 train network with train set;
 
 new_validation_score = loss when using validation set;
 
 if new_validation_score > old validation score then
  exit While loop;
 end if;
end while;
  
final score = loss when using test set;` (2/2). Sorry for the poor formatting but I cannot figure out how to add newlines in comments. So I used ; for new lines.

Comment: Nathan, thanks for your great description, I think I can code this in R, based on your example

Comment: Hi Nathan, I tried stopping the training earlier and plotted my results, it seems only with very low training steps is the test prediction MSE lowest, but it never gets very low.  I am beginning to wonder if maybe this data is just not well-suited to ANN modeling.  However, there are 3600 observations of 5 variables: 2 machines, running at 4 settings, with 1-15 power, and a fixed number of instructions, finally the response of interest is time to execute the instructions.  Is there anything about this data that would suggest it's not suited for ANN modeling?

Comment: @PatrickJ, well I can give further ideas, I wouldn't rule out ANNs just yet. I'm not familiar with R so I'll have to ask you questions about how your code operates. I see you have numbers like "156..." I'm assuming that means run instruction 1, then run instruction 5, then 6.... Where the numerical assignments of the instructions are arbitrary? What is app-number and machine number? Are these apps related to each other?

Comment: app-number and machine-number, are factor variables that I converted to numeric to run in the neural net.  Instructions are the number of instructions the machine executed.  They are large numbers like 1567383973, and have been scaled before running the nnet.

Comment: @PatrickJ what is the interval is the instruction variable being scaled? Are the app-number and machine-number presented to the neural network in such a way where each class gets its own input node? (such as one-hot-encoding or something similar)? What activation functions is the network using? Is the time variable being scaled? If so to what interval?

Comment: All variables are scaled 0-1 including instructions.  all classes for app_num and machine_num are feed into the same input node, there are 4 input nodes, instructions, nodes (a variable in the data too), machine_num, app_num.  The network is using sigmoid activation function but have also tried hyperbolictan.  Time is also scaled 0-1.

Comment: @PatrickJ If I understand you correctly, say there was a total of 5 machines. Machine 1 would feed the node a value of 0, Machine 2 would use 0.25, Machine 3 would use 0.5, Machine 4 would use 0.75, Machine 5 would use 1. Is that how it is setup? Also are the machine numbers arbitrary?

Comment: @PatrickJ do you know if the network is been trained by a back-propagation algorithm?

Comment: There are only 2 machines coded as 0 and 1, fed into the same node.  There are 4 apps coded 0, .33, .66, 1, fed into a different node than machine.  So in total 8 combinations, 4apps and 2machines.  I believe the training uses forward and back propagation.

Comment: My suggestions would be to: 1) scale the machine variable between -1 and 1 because when an input has a value of zero, its weight cannot be modified as its gradient goes to zero. Example here: https://imgur.com/a/Ik9TIDR, where $c$ is the input. 2) Replace the single app node with four nodes, where node $i$ = $1$ for app $i$, and the remaining nodes are set to -1. This is because, I assume, there is no numerical relation between the apps. App1 is no closer to App2 than it is to App3. Using four nodes allows you to make one node 'active' for each app. Similar to one-hot-encoding.

Comment: Excellent I will try this!  Thanks so much :)